# ASP.NET Oracle Sessions Remain Inactive and error for maximum exceeded maximum connect time

Tags: asp.net, oracle

My ASP.NET C# application is connection to an Oracle database, running a stored procedure, and returning a reader with the command behavior of CloseConnection. The reader itself is disposed but - the Oracle sessions persist as inactive in V$SESSION. In a few hours, this turns into an error when another customer uses the application and we receive the error 'ORA-02399: exceeded maximum connect time, you are being logged off'. Further attempts to connect to Oracle return 'ORA-01012: not logged on'

Here is the connection string:

```
User Id=UserID;Password=userPass;Data Source=(DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=TCP)  (HOST=IP.IP.IP.IP)(PORT=XXXX))(CONNECT_DATA=(SID=SID)));;Max Pool Size=5;Connection Timeout=60;Connection Lifetime=120;
```

Here is how the reader is used:

```
using (OracleDataReader dr = OraFunctions.ExecuteReader(input.ConnectionString,
                                                                    CommandType.Text,
                                                                    input.SqlStmt,
                                                                    null))
{
 while (dr.Read())
 {
 //do stuff here 
 }
 dr.Dispose();
}
```

Here is the class that connects to Oracle:

```
public static OracleDataReader ExecuteReader(string connectionString, CommandType commandType, string commandText, OracleParameter[] commandParameters) {
        OracleConnection connection = null;
        OracleCommand command = new OracleCommand();
        try {
            connection = new OracleConnection(connectionString);
            connection.Open();
            command.Connection = connection;
            command.CommandType = commandType;
            command.CommandText = commandText;

            if (commandParameters != null) {
                foreach (OracleParameter param in commandParameters) {
                    command.Parameters.Add(param);
                }
            }
            //Passing CommandBehavior.CloseConnection flag to the ExecuteReader method makes the DataReader connection to be closed when the DataReader is closed. 
            OracleDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior.CloseConnection);
            command.Dispose();
            return reader;
        } catch {
            if (connection != null) {
                command.Dispose();
                connection.Close();                    
            }
            throw;
        }
    }
```

I'm looking for any hints on why the connections aren't actually closing. I'm using Oracle.DataAccess.Client. My guess is that the datareader's command behavior isn't working and that I need to recode this as a dataset where I can explitictly close the connection without having to rely on the CommandBehavior.

Thoughts? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We never could get this worked out. We ended up disabling connection pooling and the open/inactive sessions went away in Oracle. If anyone reads this and has a suggestion on what was going wrong, I would definitely appreciate your input.

Comment: Could it be the connection object was being closed on `catch` instead of `finally` ?

Answer (score 1):

since you have connection.Open();

why didn't proper close it?

Answer (score 0):

The possible solution I'm evaluating right now is to set `Connection Lifetime` parameter below the server's value.

The idea is when connection returned to the pool after performing query, it's lifetime is checked, and connection is closed if both conditions are met:

- Connection's lifetime exceeded `Connection Lifetime` parameter value
- Number of connections opened would not be lower than `Min Pool Size` parameter value

Kudos to [Joao Morais](http://blog.ilab8.com/2011/09/02/odp-net-pooling-and-connection-request-timed-out/) for ODP.NET pooling details.